# How does exec > work in AWS EC2 user data?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, exec, process-substitution

I was writing a Terraform module for AWS EC2 that involved executing a bash in the user data section. While I was developing I had an issue in the script I wrote but neither AWS nor Terraform provided any logs for the errors in I got until I found this line in AWS support [forum](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-log-user-data/):

```
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
```

This line writes all the output of the script executed in `user_data` to `/var/log/user-data.log` successfully but I don't understand the whole line. I know `exec >` writes all the output to a file, which in this case `>(..)` but I don't understand why it's using `tee` or the need for a pipeline there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break that in to pieces:

`exec` applies redirections on the shell itself, so indeed `exec > somefile` would direct all later output from the shell and its children to that file.

Here, instead of a simple file name, we have the process substitution `>( command... )`. It tells the shell to run the command inside, and to create a some filename that's connected to the input of that command. `foo > >(bar)` is a bit like `foo | bar`, except that process substitutions can be used for more complex cases too, and don't invoke subshells like the pipeline does. (`<(command...)` would be the reverse, it would make the *output* of the command appear as if from a file.)

The command inside is `tee filename | logger ...`. `tee` copies its input both to stdout, and to the given file(s), and `logger` sends its input to the system log. (The redirection `2>/dev/console` would apply to error output from `logger`, probably it would print some errors if the system log doesn't work.)

Then there's the `2>&1`, which tells the shell to redirect error messages (stderr) also to that same process substitution.

So, after the redirection, everything the shell outputs (normal output and error output) goes (via `tee`) both to the file and (via `logger`) to syslog.

(I don't think any of that is specific to AWS or Linux, unless of course there's some particularities about the use of `logger` on AWS.)

Comment: The `exec` combined with [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) part is specific to bash - AFAIK, only bash allows that with `exec`.  Other Bourne-like shells require you to set up and use a fifo if you want to do that.  See my answer to [How can I redirect all output of a script to a file and replace passwords?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644826/how-can-i-redirect-all-output-of-a-script-to-a-file-and-replace-passwords/644862#644862)

Comment: @cas Zsh allows it as well. Ksh93 doesn't. Mksh doesn't implement process substitution. So it's 2/3 for shells with process substitution.